# Probability of Watching Two Movies in Sync

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out a good way to go about solving this problem and am hoping to get at least within the correct order of magnitude.

*Two roommates are watching TV at home. One roommate is upstairs, the other is downstairs. Roommate #1 has decided to watch a movie on DVD. Roommate #2 has decided to watch a movie on Netflix.*

*Given that the the two movies have similar frame rates (say, 23.976 FPS), what is the probability that the two movies will be synced such that they appear to be playing at the exact same time?*

Note that we do not assume the friends know the other is playing the same movie. However, given that they are friends there is a higher likelihood they would watch the same movie than, say, the probability of two randomly chosen strangers watching the same movie (in particular when we consider all the various genres and movie cultures around the world and the fact that these two roommates are from the same small town, work at the same job, and have many of the same interests).

This problem seems quite hard given the number of variables; but, I am thinking that it is solvable. Any advice on how to approach an algorithm for this... or at least help in simplifying the problem would be quite interesting!! Thanks!

Comment: I think you should make some simplifications to get started.  For instance, start by assuming they will play the same movie, and that they will both start the movie at a randomly chosen time between 8 and 9 PM.  Do you know how to approach the problem with that simplification?

Comment: I can definitely figure out ways to simplify the problem. Just trying to see if there's a way to tease out a reasonable order of magnitude given so many variables. Something like, "arguments can be made that this is fairly probable in the average human lifetime" or, on the contrary, "this is a 1 in a 1000 lifetimes event."

Comment: You're welcome! Can you work out an order of magnitude based on the simplification I suggest above, or do you need help with that, too?  Nothing you have written tells me anything about your understanding of probability calculations. Cheers!